# Remove marker listeners

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

somewhat simple problem(to explain) this time:

i have an array of markers that i equip with eventlisteners thusly:

```
for (i in markersArray) {
google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function() {        
    //stuff it does
    google.maps.event.removeListener(?????)     //remove self... but HOW?!
});}
```

as i mention in the comment, i simply want the listener to be removed once it is clicked.

problem is that i dont know what the handle for the listener is.

Comment: I didn't notice you removed the `google-maps` tag, just before I re-tagged it. I would keep it, because that's how all Google Maps API questions are tagged normally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the "addListenerOnce".  Then you don't even have to bother with removing the listener.

> addListenerOnce(instance:Object,
> eventName:string, handler:Function)
>
> Like event.AddListener, but the handler
> removes itself after handling the
> first event.

Comment: nice one, just what i needed :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `clearListeners(instance:Object, eventName:string)`http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Old post but documentation currently shows: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#removing

```
var listener1 = marker.addListener('click', aFunction);
var listener2 = marker.addListener('mouseover', bFunction);

// Remove listener1 and listener2 from marker instance.
google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure in this case you would use an array of listeners (or an object that encapsulated markers AND listeners). `google.maps.event` returns an event object. [Check the documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html).

```
var markersListeners = [];

for (i in markersArray)
{
    markersListeners[i] = google.maps.event.addListener(markersArray[i], 'click', function()
    {
        //stuff it does
        google.maps.event.removeListener(markersListeners[i]);
    });
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I haven't checked the syntax. You might also try removeListener(markersArray[i]) as I've seen it done, but do not know if it works.

Comment: removeListener(markersArray[i]) did not work for me when i tried yesterday, kept giving me api errors